# I have ubuntu xenial 16.04 how to get new versions of packages?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, cmake, doxygen

For example the cmake in my repository appears as 3.5 but my professor's appears as 3.16 which I need to run doxygen. How can I get this new version in my old ubuntu?

Comment: One way is to upgrade to a newer release, in your case 18.04.

Comment: cmake 3.10 is in Ubuntu 18.04. cmake 3.16 is in Ubuntu 20.04. To get newer software, run a newer release of Ubuntu. That's how Debian-based systems work.

Comment: For what exactly do you need cmake in respect to doxygen? Building or running? Bare running of doxygen does not require cmake. To compile you need at least version 3.3 (as far as I can see quickly, so your version should do, but I didn't try recently to build doxygen with such an old version). B.t.w. which version of doxygen?

Comment: Upgrade to a newer Ubuntu.  16.04 goes end of life in ~6 months.

Comment: @albert doxygen 1.8.11 you can build the doxygen docs directly from cmake in newer versions of cmake and it's very practical so I wish I could use it

Comment: @ThomasWard that's true... I don't want to do it during the semester though and risk having some big bug while I need the computer

Comment: I don't know by head whether or not it is possible not you could try to place a FindDoxygen.cmake from a newer cmake version into the directory with the other cmake files (probably worth a quick test)

Comment: FYI: Xubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://xubuntu.org/release/16-04/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` on your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Xubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Answer (score 1):

backup, backup, backup
then CHECK backup works
! don't forget /etc as well as /home to keep your local settings for reference/restoration

`sudo do-release-upgrade` (takes 16.04.x LTS > 18.04.x LTS)

`sudo do-release-upgrade` (takes 18.04.x LTS > 20.04.1 LTS)

OR

Clean install 20.04 and restore your backup. This allows new decisions on eg installed applications and partitions etc.
Most recent packages now available

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the binary and used it instead of the repository's. But it sure seems like I need to update my system to save some headaches.

Comment: Which binary are you talking about.

Comment: I am using Cmake's